# How do I retrieve a list of Order Statuses allowed for a given Order State?

Tags: sales-order, order-status, order-state

My understanding of Order States and Order Statuses are that a given Order State can have one or more allowed Statuses.  I've found that I can retrieve a list of *all* Statuses in the system using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses();
```

However I need the list to be limited to statuses valid for a given State.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurred to me that Magento does this when viewing an Order in the backend; specifically the "Comments History" box has a dropdown populated with allowed Statuses for the given state.

Looking into that block turned up this solution:

```
public function getStatuses()
{
    $state = $this->getOrder()->getState();
    $statuses = $this->getOrder()->getConfig()->getStateStatuses($state);
    return $statuses;
}
```

Comment: This is right. It's essentially a resource model of `sales/order_status_collection` with filtering by the given state. Take a look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Config:: getStateStatuses()`.